# Change Rows and Page Fields in all pivot tables on a page

Tags: vba

I think this is really simple but i've been staring at the same sort of code for too long this morning!

I'm looking to change the rows and filters on 6 different pivot tables on the active worksheet (which can change). Previously i had 6 different pieces of code, 1 for each pivot but as i add more options i need to make it more streamlined.

This is what i have so far

```
Sub AddMajor1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
Dim PTField As PivotFields

For Each pvtTable In ActiveSheet.PivotTables

Set PTField = .PivotFields("Division")
PTField.Orientation = xlPageField

Set PTField = .PivotFields("Wholesale / Non-Wholesale")
PTField.Orientation = xlPageField

Set PTField = .PivotFields("Major Class")
PTField.Orientation = xlRowField

Set PTField = .PivotFields("Minor Class")
PTField.Orientation = xlPageField

Set PTField = .PivotFields("Entity")
PTField.Orientation = xlPageField

Set PTField = .PivotFields("YOA")
PTField.Orientation = xlPageField

Set PTField = .PivotFields("Producing_Office")
PTField.Orientation = xlPageField

Set PTField = .PivotFields("Transaction_Handler")
PTField.Orientation = xlPageField


Next pvtTable
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong please?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem you're having?  FYI you can just write: `.PivotFields("Division").Orientation = xlPageField` without a `PTField` variable

Comment: Side note, not sure if it'll help: when I'm making multiple changes to PivotTables via VBA, I prefer to turn on ManualUpdate before I start (i.e. `pvtTable.ManualUpdate=True`), then update the table and turn it off afterwards (`pvtTable.Update: pvtTable.ManualUpdate=False`), so that it doesn't try to recalculate the entire table after every change, but does one big update at the end.  It's a bit like using `Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual` or `Application.ScreenUpdating=False`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be easier:

```vb
Sub AddMajor1()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
    Dim arr, f
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    arr = Array("Division", "Wholesale / Non-Wholesale", "Major Class", _
                 "Minor Class", "Entity", "YOA", "Producing_Office", _
                 "Transaction_Handler")
    
    For Each pvtTable In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        For Each f In arr
            pvtTable.PivotFields(f).Orientation = xlPageField
        Next f
    Next pvtTable
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```